# Ajax Function Always Returning undefined

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I need data post to action Controller model ,The data enters the model, but eventually return "undefined".
What is wrong with my codes?

```
    $(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var jdata = {
            CompanyCode: 1,
            CompanyName: "test",
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Services/getdata",
            data: JSON.stringify(jdata),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",             
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Hello: " + response.Name + " .\nCurrent Date and Time: " + response.DateTime);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

C#

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> getdata([FromBody] model tmpModel)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify `dataType: 'json'` in the AJAX call this means that you are expecting to get `json` data type back from the server.

And the line `return View();` renders  `getdata.cshtml` view as HTML document and send it back to the server as the response. It does not include `Name` or `DateTime` properties.

This is why they are **"undefined"**.

You can see how it works by returning the following object:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> getdata([FromBody] model tmpModel)
{
    return Json(new { Name = "first name", DateTime = DateTime.Now}, new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions());     
}
```